# Telerik MVC CurrencyTextBox - Custom value formatting

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

(First off, I have already posted this on the Telerik forums ([link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/numericinput/currencytextbox-help-with-custom-value-formatting.aspx)), but this site gets more traffic, so I'm hoping to get some help sooner.)

I am trying to achieve some custom value formatting with the CurrencyTextBox, but the way that the control handles values is making things decidedly hard.

What I want to do is this: if the user enters a value that does not contain a "." character, it will format that value as cents instead of dollars.  So if a user enters "16", I want the control to display (and contain a value of) $0.16.  If the user enters a value with a ".", I would like the control to function as normal.  If the user enters "16.", "16.0" or "16.00", I want the control to display (and contain a value of) "$16.00".  This application will be used by people in the retail business and this is how they expect inputs for price values to function.

However, whether I subscribe to the OnChange event or even the "blur" event on the textbox itself, it is stripping the "." character if there is either nothing after it or only 0's after it.  Example: If I enter in a value of "16.", "16.0" or "16.00", the value pulled from the textbox in javascript will be "16".  And since I have to check for the presence of the "." character, this breaks my logic to properly format the value.

So I'm looking for some help or suggestions.  Here is the javascript that I have right now to properly format the value as required.  As you can see, if the value does not contain a "." character, the value is divided by 100, which is exactly what I want.  Stripping this character is killing my logic.  :)

```
$('custom-price').find('input').live('blur', function (e) {
    var sender = $(this).data('tTextBox');
    var priceVal = $(this).val(); // $(this).attr('value') also returns the value with the character stripped, FYI
    if (priceVal.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        priceVal = priceVal / 100;
    }
    sender.value(priceVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the same using ascii code for "." operator (46). OnKeyPress if you find ascii code 46 change the format for control..

Regards,
Dhaval Shukla